# I am trying to mimic the connection of my softether vpn to setup a openvpn with TLS 1.2 instead of SSL

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ssl, tls, softether

I am trying to setup a openvpn with tls 1.2 instead of ssl with tcp, as in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I mimic the connection like the softether (on the left) in order to setup openvpn (on the right)?

Comment: What TLS version does your OpenVPN show as being negotiated? (It's probably TLS in reality but with the SSL-compatible headers.)

Comment: i dont know , how can i check that

Comment: I just want to use open vpn because soft ether has secureNAT which makes the connection slow and i have a network provider that only soft ether vpn works on that connection